# nodejs is not publishing all messages in timeout mqtt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I am testing my `mqtt broker`. I have made 1000 clients. These 1000 clients publish one message in 2 seconds, means in 2 seconds 1000 messages will be published. But when I use `setInterval`, 1000 messages are not published. Almost half of messages will be published and when I publish without `setInterval` all of the messages are delivered.

It is due to my nodejs code but I am unable to understand what exactly is happening. I am using emqtt broker.

Here is my code:

publish.js

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
 client[index] = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883',{qos:2})  
}

setInterval(function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
        var payload = JSON.stringify({
          id:index,
          timestamp:Date.now()
        });
        client[index].publish("drivers", payload,{qos:2},function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log("There is an error in publishing ",err);
          }
        });
    }
}, 2000)
```

Subscriber.js

```
var client2 = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883',{qos:2});
var fs = require('fs');
client2.subscribe("drivers", {
    qos: 2
});
client2.on("message", function (topic, payload) {
        payload = JSON.parse(payload.toString());
        fs.appendFile('drivers', payload.id+"\n", function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
          });
})
```

What is happening with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors on printed by the client or in the broker logs?

Comment: No. Nothing is printing.

Comment: And the broker logs?

Comment: Nope No logs for today.